# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404> Spring Boot Page Not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller

**CheckoutController**

```java
@Controller
@Profile("!test")
public class CheckoutController {

  private MonetaryAmount total = Money.of(0, EURO);
  private final UniqueInventory<UniqueInventoryItem> inventory;
  private final Katalog catalogue;

  private List<UniqueInventoryItem> history = new ArrayList();
  
  @Autowired
  public CheckoutController(UniqueInventory<UniqueInventoryItem> _inventory, Katalog _catalogue){
    inventory = _inventory;
    catalogue = _catalogue;
  }
  
  //!  Get Mappings

  //@GetMapping("/checkout")
  @RequestMapping("/checkout")
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('WORKER')")
  public String checkout(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("total", this.total);
    model.addAttribute("history", this.history);
    model.addAttribute("controller", this);

    return "checkout"; // thymleafe located in proper path, visible when logged in 
  }
}
```

**TestingController**

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class CheckoutControllerTests {

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @BeforeEach
  public void pre() {
    // code
  }

  @Test
  public void checkout() throws Exception {
    // TODO Error msg: status expected:<200> but was:<404>
        mockMvc.perform(get("/checkout").with(user("paul").roles("WORKER")))
      .andExpect(status().isOk());


  }
}
```

Where it says "/checkout" above, I could put all other available routes which are accepted, but not this one and I do not know why. Again, it's visible to my once logged in running the project.

I tried using RequestMapping instead of GetMapping but that didnt work either. I googled with no success, in most cases people did not actually point to the right html file but thats not the case here either. I am lost at this point, asked my friends and colleagues with no success.

If you have any **clue** what it could be, improper mvc setup, yadada, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting profiles. Your controller is annotated with `@Profile("!test")` while your test is executing with `@ActiveProfiles("test")`.

Comment: Changing it to `@Profile("test")` then obviously did work. Thanks man!